# Github action the `set-output` command is deprecated

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow, building-github-actions

I have the following github action, I am given the following warnings:

```
build-android
The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. 
Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: 
https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
```

But I'm not using `set-output`.

```yaml
on: workflow_dispatch

name: Build
jobs:
  build-android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build Android Release
        run: cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

      - name: Read package.json
        uses: tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions@v1
        id: package-version

      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: app-release.apk
          path: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/

      - name: Create Github Release
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"
          tag: "v${{ steps.package-version.outputs.version }}"
          replacesArtifacts: false
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          allowUpdates: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your workflow is not using `set-output`, then you need to look at your external action dependencies. One or both of them are using the outdated syntax.

For JS based actions, `@actions/core` added support for output env files in [1.10.0](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/packages/core/RELEASES.md#1100)

1. `tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions@v1`

v1 of this action was released in 2019, so undoubtedly this is one source of your problems. It does use [set-output](https://github.com/tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions/blob/master/src/main.ts#L13), but from the old version of the `@actions/core`.

You are also likely getting a warning about [node 12](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/) deprecation.

2. `ncipollo/release-action@v1`.

This action's latest update was in December 2022, is running on node 16, is using [set-output](https://github.com/ncipollo/release-action/blob/v1/lib/Outputs.js#L30-L32), but has the [correct version](https://github.com/ncipollo/release-action/blob/v1/yarn.lock#L5) of `@actions/core`.

Based on this, #1 is your problem action. Now you have a few choices, add an issue requesting an update, submit a PR with the necessary changes, or find a different action that supports your needs that is more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not using `set-output`.

Luckily we don't fight over a beer for that statement, but if you remove step-by-step from behind and execute per each removal, you'll identify which step removal removes the warning.

Then find the `uses` statement of the removal and check for updates. Also report the issue if not yet reported. Restore, update and re-try.

TLDR: `uses` uses other uses, too. Check all actions in use for updates. If a culprit and no updates, prepare for replacement.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by others above, the "`set-output` *command is deprecated*" warning is now showing on various Github Actions where Actions maintainers haven't updated their repos to address this recent change in Github workflow yet (https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/). Another warning - 'Node.js 12 actions are deprecated' - is also triggered for most of these Github Actions for a similar reason (see https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/ for details). For instance, I am currently facing the same issue with `FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy` feature.

I checked the repo for `tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions@v1` that apparently triggers the warning in your case and found the relevant issue already open for this repo:
https://github.com/tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions/issues/15

So, if you keep using this Github Action, to get rid of this warning you should probably reach out to the Action maintainer (@tyankatsu0105) on Github asking them to resolve this issue, or create a PR on Github fixing the redundant dependencies to `tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions@v1` yourself asking the Action maintainer to merge it.

Comment: Just for you to know, a similar issue on FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy has been fixed, so the warning about set-output command doesn't show there anymore. Here's the link to the fix https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/pull/279. Thus I advise users of tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions to reach out to the Action maintainer on Github and suggest a similar fix.